# How can I debug why my extension does not start?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

- I am following the instructions at https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension.
- I have the new extension's source code open in VS Code.
- I press `F5` (or manually press the `Run Extension` button in the debug panel).
- A new window opens, but the extension is not loaded. I don't see any logs, no command, no nothing. It just does not work.

How can I find out why the extension did not get loaded?

Answer (score 0):

The way to debug VS Code initialization *et al.* is to use the `Toggle Developer Tools` feature:

1. Press `F5` and wait for the new VS Code window to open:
2. Press `F1` → `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools`:
   [image]
3. And there it is: The error shows up in the dev tools console.
   [image]